# Problem running gazebo: Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_control.so

Tags: gazebo, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running gazebo on hydro. 
I get the following message after the Model is spawned successfully:

```
Error [Plugin.hh:138] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_control.so: libgazebo_ros_control.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Thanks for your help :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187417/problem-running-gazebo:-failed-to-load-plugin-libgazebo_ros_control.so/) by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on ROS Answers with karma: 862 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might need to install the `ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-control` package (or `ros-indigo-...` depending on which version of ROS you're using).

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-07-22**:
this was the case. Thanks for your help